# Merge Sort Stack Overflow vb.net

Tags: vb.net, stack-overflow, mergesort

In my project, I want to make a merge sort on a list of one of my project's class :

Firstly, I made the comparison's operators for this class

```vb
Public Class Programme

    Private DateLimite As Date


    Public Shared Operator >(ByVal p1 As Programme, ByVal p2 As Programme) As Boolean
         Return p1.acces_DateLimite > p2.acces_DateLimite
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <(ByVal p1 As Programme, ByVal p2 As Programme) As Boolean
         Return p1.acces_DateLimite < p2.acces_DateLimite
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator >=(ByVal p1 As Programme, ByVal p2 As Programme) As Boolean
         Return p1.acces_DateLimite >= p2.acces_DateLimite
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <=(ByVal p1 As Programme, ByVal p2 As Programme) As Boolean
         Return p1.acces_DateLimite <= p2.acces_DateLimite
    End Operator

End Class
```

After that, I made the merge sort algorithm

```vb
Public Function InsertListe(element As Programme, sequence As List(Of Programme)) As List(Of Programme)
    Dim list = New List(Of Programme)
    If sequence.Count = 0 Then
        list.Add(element)
        Return list
    ElseIf element <= sequence.First Then
        sequence.Insert(0, element)
        Return sequence
    Else
        list.Add(sequence(0))
        list.AddRange(InsertListe(element, sequence.GetRange(1, sequence.Count - 1)))
        Return list
    End If
End Function


Public Function Merge(subSeq1 As List(Of Programme), subSeq2 As List(Of Programme)) As List(Of Programme)
    If subSeq1.Count = 0 Then
        Return subSeq2
    ElseIf subSeq2.Count = 0 Then
        Return subSeq1
    Else
        Return Merge(subSeq1.GetRange(1, subSeq1.Count - 1), InsertListe(subSeq1(0), subSeq2))
    End If
End Function


Public Function MergeSort(sequence As List(Of Programme)) As List(Of Programme)
    Dim n = sequence.Count
    If n = 0 Or n = 1 Then
        Return sequence
    Else
        Return Merge(MergeSort(sequence.GetRange(0, (n + 1) / 2)), _
                     MergeSort(sequence.GetRange((n + 1) / 2, n - ((n + 1) / 2))))
    End If
End Function
```

But when I call it on a 'List(Of Programme)', a StackOverFlowException is thrown 
and I can't find why. I was looking at the call stack, and only the ''MergeSort'' function is called even if n is greater than 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: stackoverflow on a recursive function = recursing too deeply and/or infinitely.

Comment: My lists have only 10 elements max and i debug it step by step the run line underline the return statement where the merge function is called and it doesn't call the method merge in the call stack

Comment: then you've probably got an infinite loop.

Comment: I can't find it, that's why i'm asking for help.

Comment: if you cant find the cause for your infinite recursion the solution is quite simple : convert your entire algorithm into iteration. Recursion is error-prone, can be hard to understand and is **extremely** inefficient. Such a conversion is easier than you might think ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing your `Programme` class with a `UInteger` (just an example of plain datatype) and minor style tweaks, everything works for me:

```
Public Shared Sub Test()
    Dim oPRNG As New Random
    For ndxTrial As Integer = 1 To 10
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Trial # {0}", ndxTrial)
        Dim nItems As Integer = oPRNG.Next(5, 25)
        Dim auValues As New List(Of UInteger)(nItems)
        For ndxItem As Integer = 0 To nItems - 1
            auValues.Add(CUInt(oPRNG.Next(0, 100)))
        Next
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Random: {0}", FormatList(auValues))
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Sorted: {0}", FormatList(MergeSort(auValues)))
        Console.Out.WriteLine()
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Function FormatList(ByVal auValues As List(Of UInteger)) As String
    Return String.Format("{{ {0} }}", String.Join(", ", auValues))
End Function

Public Shared Function InsertListe(element As UInteger, sequence As List(Of UInteger)) As List(Of UInteger)
    Dim list As New List(Of UInteger)
    If sequence.Count = 0 Then
        list.Add(element)
        Return list
    ElseIf element <= sequence.First Then
        sequence.Insert(0, element)
        Return sequence
    Else
        list.Add(sequence(0))
        list.AddRange(InsertListe(element, sequence.GetRange(1, sequence.Count - 1)))
        Return list
    End If
End Function


Public Shared Function Merge(subSeq1 As List(Of UInteger), subSeq2 As List(Of UInteger)) As List(Of UInteger)
    If subSeq1.Count = 0 Then
        Return subSeq2
    ElseIf subSeq2.Count = 0 Then
        Return subSeq1
    Else
        Return Merge(subSeq1.GetRange(1, subSeq1.Count - 1), InsertListe(subSeq1(0), subSeq2))
    End If
End Function


Public Shared Function MergeSort(sequence As List(Of UInteger)) As List(Of UInteger)
    Dim n As Integer = sequence.Count
    If n = 0 Or n = 1 Then
        Return sequence
    Else
        Return Merge(MergeSort(sequence.GetRange(0, (n + 1) \ 2)), _
                     MergeSort(sequence.GetRange((n + 1) \ 2, n - ((n + 1) \ 2))))
    End If
End Function
```

Thus the first thing to get rid in your code are those **floating-point** division operations ­— use **back** slash (integer division) instead of forward: that way you will guarantee proper rounding.

Related to this, it is also worth noting the importance of being explicit about your intentions and never rely on automatic type deduction. Instead of

```
    Dim n = sequence.Count
```

write

```
    Dim n As Integer = sequence.Count
```

and instead of

```
    Dim list = New List(Of Programme)
```

write

```
    Dim list As New List(Of Programme)
```

Moreover, always enable `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit`, as well as disable `Option Infer` in project properties. That will save you much time from debugging mysterious errors.

Overall, I hope this “project” is just your home assignment for language learning rather than a real application, because the selected algorithm together with selected container (a List in .Net is simply a dynamically reallocated array) is suboptimal beyond imagination.